# Appcompat_v7 -->res -->layout error - Orientation Lint Error

Tags: java, android, eclipse, layout, android-appcompat

I keep getting an error in my `abc_action_bar_decor_overlay.xml`.

Error: "Wrong orientation? No orientation specified, and the default is horizontal, yet this layout has multiple children where at least one has `layout_width="match_parent"`"

```
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/top_action_bar"   <---error
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_gravity="top">

    <android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarContainer
        android:id="@+id/action_bar_container"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
           style="?attr/actionBarStyle"
           android:gravity="top">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `LinearLayout` must have the attribute [`android:orientation`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#attr_android%3aorientation) as follows:

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/top_action_bar"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top" >
```

This attribute provides the direction of the children views, see:

**vertical** *(a row)*

```
<LinearLayout>
    [View 1]
    [View 2]
    [View 3]
</LinearLayout>
```

**horizontal** *(a column)*

```
<LinearLayout> [View 1] [View 2] [View 3] </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Its probably from Lint Error Checking.

Here is how I did it for this *Wrong Orientation* error(eclipse):

1) Window -> Preferences -> Android - Lint Error Checking.

2) In Search box 'Issues', type Orientation -> select the row

3) Set 'Severity' from dropdown to 'Warning'

---

Project -> Clean.